# send data from one table to another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this table I want when I click on a link in a table row that do a redirect to another page the data will be sent to the new page that can help me I have not found how to start

I'm really stuck
code table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>            


        <th>Date</th>
        <th>provider</th>
        <th>CI</th>
        <th>CELL</th>
        <th>BSC</th>
        <th>Commentaire</th>
        <th>nbr</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Modify.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
        <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Info.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
        <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Male.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
        <th>type_alertes</th>




    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>




         <div class="textbox">
        <h2> Information KPI dégradées</h2>

            <div class="textbox_content" id="kpi_dégrades">
 {% for liste in listes %}

    <tr class="gradeU">
    <td>{{ liste.DAT }} </td>
    <td>{{ liste.PROVIDER}} </td>
    <td>{{ liste.CI}} </td>
    <td>{{ liste.CELL}} </td>
    <td>{{ liste.BSC}}</td>
    <td>{{ liste.Cmts}}</td>
    <td >{{ liste.nbr}}</td>
    <td>{{ liste.TYPE}}</td>
    <td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td>
    <td onclick="getInfo('{{ liste.CELL}}')">Information KPI dégradés</td>
    <td>{{ liste.user_name}}</td>
    <td>{{ liste.type_alertes}}</td>



</tr>


{% endfor %}
        </div>
        </div>

</tbody>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `<a href="page.html?arg=val">link text</a>`?

Comment: add an `<a>` with `href="your-other-page.php?rowID=XXX"`?

Comment: javascript/Jquery needed here, instead of a `a` tag use a `onclick` event that calls to a function that gets the data needed and submits it to a php script

Comment: @Naryl Never use JavaScript when HTML or CSS will do. You never know when a user will have JS disabled.

Comment: yeah we don't know if he needed just and ID, something the user typed in a input, or other stuff you don't have when you write the href :S

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable to find out the rowID.

http://example.com/page.php?rowID=xx

In your main table have a link for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields on next page that will store your data on next page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr onclick="window.location="newPageLocation?value = this.innerHTML">  
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>provider</th>
    <th>CI</th>
    <th>CELL</th>
    <th>BSC</th>
    <th>Commentaire</th>
    <th>nbr</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Modify.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
    <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Info.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
    <th><img src="{{ asset('image/Male.png') }}" ALIGN="CENTER"/></th>
    <th>type_alertes</th>
```

in the next page
using javascript get the value from td